# How to store and get an object without destroying the type in localStorage?

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I'm working on an AngularJS project with TypeScript.

A `person` is an object of the `Person` class. I need to store `person` object in `localStorage` and retrieve it with its type.

Answer (score 13):

[window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can [store](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) only strings. You can use JSON to serialize your object and retrieve it back.

```
class Person {

    constructor(public name:string) {

    }
}

let person = new Person('Peter');
localStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify(person));
let personFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person')) as Person;

console.log({
    person: person,
    personFromStorage: personFromStorage
});
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96977/discussion-between-user3264864-and-martin-vseticka).

Comment: From what I understand, calling JSON.Stringify you will lose your methods, so pulling them back out from the session then trying to call a method afterwards, you will get "is not a function". I ran into this when I tried to move all of my methods into my model, like I would in other languages, only to realize I could not save the "object" with methods as anything but a string. If anyone has a (simple) solution I'd love to know.

Answer (score 6):

While Martin's answer works for classes without methods. For classes with methods you can try this:

```
let personFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person')) as Person;

let person = new Person('');
Object.assign(person , personFromStorage);
```