# How do I persist and retrieve typescript objects using pouchdb?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pouchdb

I'm extremely new to typescript and webdev in general and looking to use pouchdb in a typescript project to persist my objects. I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to do this, and documentation is pretty scarce.

i've got typescript objects that derive from a Document base class with the required _id and _rev fields. Am I on the right track here? remotely close?

Here's my attempt at creating a Document base class that smells like something that should go in a PouchDB database-

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

// Base class for all objects which are persisted in database
export class Document {

    readonly type: string;
    readonly _id: string;
    private _rev?: string; //set by database when document is inserted

    constructor(type: string, id_suffix?: string) {
        this.type = type;
        let unique_id: string = uuid();

        if (id_suffix === undefined) {
            this._id = '${type}_${unique_id}'
        }
        else {
            this._id = '${type}_${id_suffix}_${unique_id}'
        }
    }
}
```

I can insert it into the database, apparently

```
let db = new PouchDB('my-database');
let mydoc = Document('mydoc');

db.put(t)

let output = db.get(t._id); //Promise<PouchDB.Core.IdMeta & PouchDB.Core.GetMeta>
```

Can someone help my get my object back?

Comment: I strongly recommend you start off by trying the async/await examples of ´put´, ´get´ and ´alldocs´, atleast. You can gradually add to that base to increase complexity. All the commands work with JSON objects, which you can create, easily, from JavaScript objects with ´JSON.stringify()´

Comment: @MartinBramwell I do appreciate the tips. I'm not too worried about the complexity of using promises, while i'm not too familiar with typescript/javascript i'm quite comfortable with aynchronous code from other languages. I can also create JSON objects, what i'm trying to find out is the idiomatic way to get back to concrete typescript objects from a json object.

Comment: PouchDB functions return normal JavaScript objects.

Comment: @MartinBramwell perhaps you could show me a code example to explain what you mean? To be clear, I'm aware that a JSON object is returned, by question is about idiomatically converting this back into a concrete TypeScript object.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work...

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

// Base class for all objects which are persisted in database
export class Document {

    readonly type: string;
    readonly _id: string;
    private _rev?: string; //set by database when document is inserted

    constructor(type: string, id_suffix?: string) {
        this.type = type;
        let unique_id: string = uuid();

        if (id_suffix === undefined) {
            this._id = '${type}_${unique_id}'
        }
        else {
            this._id = '${type}_${id_suffix}_${unique_id}'
        }
    }
}

db.put(t);

let output = db.get<Document>(t._id).then(function (doc){
    let x: Document = doc;
    return x;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the records, as you cast the return value (eg. `as Document`) from a plain object (Pouchdb store JSON objects), you lost the prototype. So you have to rebuild an instance from scratch.

For example :

```
let output = db.get<Document>(t._id).then(function (doc){
    return new Document(
        doc.type,
        doc. id_suffix
    );
})
```

Or as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493769/5727772), using `Object.assign` (haven't test this way).